# how to remove/detect only white spaces in a textbox, such that "ALL WHITESPACE EQUALS NULL"

Tags: vb.net

must stop the user from proceeding if the textbox is null,

if the textbox has only spaces in it.

i tried . trim but that doesnot work, still spaces are excapted as valid characters.

Comment: try `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to check, I didn't get the question well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4 - [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

```
If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(theTextBox.Text) Then
    ' process the error.
End If
```

Otherwise [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(theTextBox.Text.Trim()) Then
    ' process the error.
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim tempstring As String
        tempstring = TextEdit1proceed.Text.Trim.ToString
        MessageBox.Show(tempstring)


        If tempstring = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a Username")
        Else
```

Answer (score 0):

Picture the following scenario:

```
var inputString = "      ";      
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputString)
{
}
```

But also note, for future reference (or should your version of the framework not support the above method), that you may have been using `Trim` incorrectly; you can't just call`Trim` to manipulate the string, a new string must be created and therefore you need to assign it, as follows:

```
var trimmedString = inputString.Trim();
```

So, if required, you could do:

```
var inputString = "      ";
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString.Trim())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Validating event of TextBox

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim() = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please, enter valid entry!!!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Being pedantic I prefer TextBox1.Text.Trim() = String.Empty